# How to communicate from children process(exec) with parent through pipe()?

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, exec

I have these two files and i call exec.c from main.c using exec(). As far as I understand exec.c should inherit the pipe but it says there is no link pipe in exec.c. What is the problem here?

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define die(e)                      \
    do                              \
    {                               \
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e); \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);         \
    } while (0);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int link[2];
    pid_t pid;
    char foo[4096];

    if (pipe(link) == -1)
        die("pipe");

    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
        die("fork");

    if (pid == 0)
    {

        dup2(link[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(link[0]);
        close(link[1]);
        execvp("./exec", argv);
        die("execl");
    }
    else
    {

        close(link[1]);
        int nbytes = read(link[0], foo, sizeof(foo));
        printf("Output: (%.*s)\n", nbytes, foo);
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

exec.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char a;
    a='A';
    write(link[1],&a,sizeof(a));


    return 0;
}
```

I am just practicing and want to output the data that is save from pipe()

What I am doing wrong, can you help me to debug?
TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `main.c` program you connect the pipe through standard output of the child process.

That means the child process passes information to the parent process through its normal standard output.

From this follows that the `exec.c` program could be as simple as this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("A");
}
```

---

More specifically, your `exec.c` Source file doesn't have any idea of the pipe, and definitely not about the variable `link`, and will simply fail to build.

Comment: How can I make it to be connected to the pipe?

Comment: @newyernar You're already doing that. Remove all contents of the `main` function in the `exec.c` source file, and replace it with the single `printf` call shown in the answer.

Comment: Thank you, but what if I dont want to use printf to send via pipe a single value string but somehow send array. How can i do this?

Comment: @newyernar Just write to the standard output, using any function you'd like. Using `write`, like in your existing example, then use `STDOUT_FILENO` as the descriptor to write to.